# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: goToByScroll using CoffeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This javascript code is working fine.

```
  function goToByScroll(id){
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 50},'slow');
  }
```

I'm having a hard time with its CoffeScript version. I had the following code on `application.js.coffee`.

```
  goToByScroll = (id) ->
    $("html,body").animate ->
      scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top - 50
    , "slow"
```

But I get the error

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: goToByScroll
```

Any idea what may be causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What **Jordan** said is correct: you'll need to somehow export your function
to a globally-accessible scope or compile your CoffeeScript with the `bare`
flag, preventing the output from being wrapped in an anonymous function.

Additionally, you've got a bit of a bug in your CoffeeScript: you're passing
a callback to `jQuery.animate`, not an object literal like you do in the
JavaScript code. For equivalent behavior, you probably want something like
this:

```
goToByScroll = (id) ->
    $("html,body").animate
        # CoffeeScript supports string interpolation, that's what the #{}
        # syntax does
        scrollTip: $("##{id}").offset().top - 50
    , "slow"

# Then, export it by attaching it to the window or some object accessible
# outside this scope
window.goToByScroll = goToByScroll
```

Answer (score 4):

If the function is in a different file it is inside a closure and not accessible.  Either attach the function to the window object or declare it in the same file.